# ERROR 1054 when login in admin section

Tags: sql, joomla-3.9

An exception has occurred while executing:

```
SELECT t0.id AS id_1,
       t0.first_name AS first_name_2,
       t0.middle_name AS middle_name_3,
       t0.last_name AS last_name_4,
       t0.email AS email_5,
       t0.password AS password_6,
       t0.roles AS roles_7,
       t0.is_terms_accepted AS is_terms_accepted_8,
       t0.phone_number AS phone_number_9,
       t0.last_login_time AS last_login_time_10,
       t0.is_active AS is_active_11,
       t0.application_type AS application_type_12,
       t0.is_password_created AS is_password_created_13,
       t0.profile_linked_at AS profile_linked_at_14,
       t0.account_created_at AS account_created_at_15,
       t0.password_reset_token AS password_reset_token_16,
       t0.is_reset_token_valid AS is_reset_token_valid_17,
       t0.my_profile_id AS my_profile_id_18,
       t0.account_created_by_id AS account_created_by_id_19,
       t0.approved_by_id AS approved_by_id_20
FROM user t0
WHERE t0.email = ?
  AND t0.is_active = ?
LIMIT 1
```

I'm using these parameters:

```
["ict@prisk.or.ke", 1]
```

Error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.roles' in 'field list'

Comment: Those don't look like Joomla core queries. Enable debug and post call stack. If you can't access Global Configuration, you have to do it by modifying `configuration.php`.

Comment: ERROR 1054 "Unknown column in 'field list' error" is a MySQL database error which means that a field / column does not exist in one of your database tables.